# JQuery - button from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I`m from Russia, so sorry for bad English.
I am loading a part of webpage with ajax.

for example

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#link1").click(function(){
    $.post("ajax.php", { act: "load" },
    function(data) {
        $("#content").html(data);
    });
});
</script>

<a href="#" id="link1">Click</a>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Ajax.php returns: `<input type="button" id="button1" value="test">`

Now I want to control this button from script too.
I`m trying:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#link1").click(function(){
        $.post("ajax.php", { act: "load" },
        function(data) {
            $("#content").html(data);
        });
    });

    $("#button1").click(function(){
        alert('test');
    });
</script>
```

but this doesn`t work. Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#button1").click(...);
```

won't do anything because the element `#button1` **does not exist yet** when you run that code (`$("#button1")` will not select any element).

Either put it in the callback of your Ajax request:

```
$.post("ajax.php", { act: "load" }, function(data) {
    $("#content").html(data);
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        alert('test');
    });
});
```

or use [**`.delegate()`**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) / [**`.live()`**](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$("#content").delegate('#button1', 'click', function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to use:

```
$("#button1").live('click', function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

The [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function allows events to be fired from elements that are dynamically added to the page.

Answer (score 1):

this part:

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

is attaching the click handler to any existing dom elements with the Id `button1` *when the script is first run*.  Since that button doesn't exist until you manually click on your `link1` element, you need to change how you're adding the event handler.  Try using the `live` method from jquery to do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#link1").click(function(){
        $.post("ajax.php", { act: "load" },
        function(data) {
            $("#content").html(data);
        });
    });

    $("#button1").live('click', function(){
        alert('test');
    });
</script>
```

This will attach the event handler to any matching elements as soon as they become "live" in the document.  More here: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

You are registering the click event for any buttons that are *currently* on page. By the time your link has been clicked, its already been registered.

Use the live event as mentioned by Richard D. That sets the event for any buttons that *ever* match the id you are using as your selector.